# Debugger.Break on visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, break

I try to debug my windows service using Debugger.Break() on Visual Studio 2010 beta 2 Ultimate on Vista 64 bits. Nothing is happening when I execute my code...

Someone have a idea?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I use this technique as well to debug services of different types.

Answer (score 0):

Have you attached the services process to the Debugger?

Debug Menu > Attach to process

Kindness,

Dan